# Adding a new library to existing conda environment

Tags: python, conda

I created a conda environment using the instructions here: https://www.osc.edu/resources/getting_started/howto/howto_add_python_packages_using_the_conda_package_manager and now I need to add a python library to it. How do I edit the conda environment and add a single library?

Comment: Are you asking about `conda install <package>`?

Comment: `source activate {nameofenv}` or on windows `activate {nameofenv}` and then `conda install...`

Comment: @AntonvBR, thanks, so once I deactivate the environment and try activating it again, the library will not need to be installed again?

Comment: @user308827 Exactly

Comment: thanks, happy to accept this as an answer if you create one.

Comment: @user308827 Sure... I will look for dupe too. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by activating the environment:

`source activate {nameofenv}` or on windows `activate {nameofenv}`

After use `conda install...`